# How can I delete a user registered in Firebase with an email and password? Using React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working with React and Firebase but I can not find how to eliminate registered users with email and password.

I have found two options: From the firebase console or using **auth().CurrentUser.delete()** but this deletes my own user.

Does anyone know how to achieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be running your own secure backend ([Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) counts), along with the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).  With the SDK, you can [manage users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users), including [deleting a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).

You can't do any of this securely on the fronend.  You need a secure backend to use the Admin SDK.